# Rx + Moxy + garbage collector

Tags: java, android, rxjava, сборщик-мусора, moxy

Всем привет!

Не помешает ли запущенный `Flowable` процесс (который ждёт изменений источников данных) в `onFirstViewAttach()` `Presenter`-a сборщику мусора "прибивать" этот самый `Presenter`. Пример:

```
@Override
protected void onFirstViewAttach() {
    super.onFirstViewAttach();
    Flowable.combineLatest(some source and Function)
        .map((...)->someGetMethod())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe((...)-> getViewState().someViewInterfaceMethod());
}
```

Comment: Помешает. Создайте в Presenter'e инстанс CompositeDisposable и поместите в него disposable от данной подписки.А в onDestroy() Presenter'а вызывайте compositeDisposable.clear()